# Disable left click hold when right click starts

Tags: autohotkey

I tried this but cant get a correct result.
How do i disable left click Down when i start holding right click?

```
rb=true


~$LButton::
while (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") and !rb) 
{
continue
}
MsgBox,hi
Return

~$RButton::
rb=1
MsgBox,bye
while GetKeyState("RButton", "P") {
rb=1
    continue
    }
rb=0
Return
```

On pressing Rbutton the while loop in Lbutton doesnt exit(only exits on Rbutton release)!? why

[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owoom.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried? We are not here to do your work. We are here to help you with what went wrong.

Comment: Currently your script doesn't do anything at all regarding the buttons. There is nothing in the script that would change the behavior of any button in any way. Also, I'm assuming the msgboxes are just for testing purposes? If not, it's good to note that your script will be halted while a msgbox is being displayed. But anyway, can you explain better what you want? If right click is held down, left click shouldn't do anything? Or?

Comment: @0x464e yes msgbox is for test. the rb is a bool which should be turned on when RButton so the while loop in Lbutton exits. but it doesnt

Comment: @0x464e this is what i want: Im holding down Lclick, as soon as i start holding Rclick iwant the Lclick to stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but from the comments:
*"Im holding down Lclick, as soon as i start holding Rclick iwant the Lclick to stop"*

The answer to that is simply:

```
~RButton::
    if (GetKeyState("LButton"))
        SendInput, {LButton Up}
return
```

Comment: ok this is kind of what i want thanks but the Rbutton doesnt Click it only disables Lbutton

Comment: The `~` modifier is used, so right click does go through as well. If it doesn't work as expected for you, I don't really know what to say. Probably something related to the game you're trying to make this for. And I can't really do any testing since I don't know which game, or if I knew, I probably don't have the game.